# Move base global planners switching

Tags: navigation, base-global-planner, sbpl-lattice-planner, navfn, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
After reading http://answers.ros.org/question/9888/switching-global-planner/

I've got some questions regarding the issue of switching global planner.
As I can understand the global planner is a parameter of move_base, and it's displayed in the dynamic reconfigure but I cannot change it online?

I need to use different planners and different configurations controlled by a supervisor node.
For now the options are:

Kill the move_base node and relaunch it ( roslaunch api ???)

Keep two move_base nodes online and simply reroute the goals.

Somehow change all parameters on the fly using dynamic_reconfigure.

Anyone has experience and doing something similiar, I think this would be a great addition to ros Navigation.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37821/move-base-global-planners-switching/) by [fmarques](https://answers.ros.org/users/1293/fmarques/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2012-07-03

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The consensus answer to the [question you linked](http://answers.ros.org/question/9888/switching-global-planner/) was to write a supervisory planner that switches between other planners when needed. That would be done using a single `move_base` instance.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fmarques](https://answers.ros.org/users/1293/fmarques/) on 2012-07-04**:
Thank you I did a simplified version of that( 2 planners only hard coded) works great

**Comment by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on 2017-07-11**:
hi, @joq, I also want to implement same function. However, I can't understand what supervisory planner is and don't know how to implement it. I also asked question, please see [this link](http://answers.ros.org/question/265958/how-to-switch-the-planner-of-move_base-during-the-navigation/)

**Comment by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on 2017-07-11**:
hi, @fmarques, Have you solved your question? would you like to answer [my question](http://answers.ros.org/question/265958/how-to-switch-the-planner-of-move_base-during-the-navigation/)? Thank you!